# How to overwrite value at any new line number in text file without loops

Tags: python

I have a writer function which needs to write a value into the text file at the specified line number which doesn't follow a sequence. For Example
1 100 (At line 1 write value 100)
7 50 (At line 7 write value 50)
4 40 (At line 4 write value 40)

The text file can be fully blank, and I want to add a value to any desired line number and the values in between can be left as blank. If the same line number is received again, it should overwrite it with the new value.

Comment: Did you try it before coming for an answer? if yes, can you update your post with your code?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I checked itertools.islice, but it doesn't add new lines at any any line number, it can add only within the existing number of lines or at the end. If there are 10 lines. I cannot add a 15th line using islice.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution i found after racking my brains for 24 hours.
list_1 = [1, 2, None,3,4,5]
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for item in list_1:
        if item == None:
            item = ""
        file.write("{}\n".format(str(item)))